# Post Comment on wordpress Blogs

Tags: wordpress, post, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest

I was working on a project in which I have to post comment on by wordpress blog that should contain the text user entered in text box.I have been trying to user `HttpWebRequest`but it fails and returns 404 not found. Even the link is not broken.here is my code

fore test purpose i have hard coded the entries in `string post`

```
 string post = "author=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("afnan") + "&email=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ifi@ifi.com") + "&url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("abcd.com") +
                    "&comment=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("no comments");
                HttpWebRequest wrWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://testing.autoprofitbot.com/blogtest/2011/05/13/call-3-computer-repair-services-put-to-test-4/wp-comments-post.php?") as HttpWebRequest;

                wrWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                wrWebRequest.ContentLength = post.Length;
                wrWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                wrWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

                //// Post to the login form.
                StreamWriter swRequestWriter = new
                StreamWriter(wrWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
                swRequestWriter.Write(post);
                swRequestWriter.Close();

                // Get the response.
                HttpWebResponse hwrWebResponse =
                (HttpWebResponse)wrWebRequest.GetResponse();

                // Have some cookies.
                CookieCollection ccCookies = hwrWebResponse.Cookies;

                // Read the response
                StreamReader srResponseReader = new
                StreamReader(hwrWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
                string strResponseData = srResponseReader.ReadToEnd();
                srResponseReader.Close();
                webBrowser1.DocumentText = strResponseData;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 problems with your code:

1. the post data lacks 2 parameters
2. the `WebRequest.Create` is not correct
3. the referrer url is missing; use `livehttpheaders` or `httpfox` to get the correct headers format!

Comment: can you do an example that demonstrate simple form posting Thanks